# Composer init, cria arquivo em diretórios diferente

Tags: composer

Instalei composer, git, github na partição C:, tenho servidor apache24 e php7 inatalado na partição D:, entrei pasta htdocs/SBFC meu site do servidor na linha de comando e fiz um composer init, transcorreu tudo certo mas executar o comando dir na pasta não havia nenhum arquivo, fiz uma procura no computador achei tudo em uma pasta oculta no diretório C:, chamada de C:\VTRoot\HarddiskVolume4\WebServer\Apache24\htdocs\SBFC  com os arquivos criados conforme imagem abaixo 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém pode me explicar o que acontece, desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: achei o que estava dando errado, era meu antivírus comodo, a instalação do activerecord ia pra outra pasta chamada VTRoot,  troquei de antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

achei o que estava dando errado, era meu antivírus comodo, a instalação do activerecord ia pra outra pasta chamada VTRoot,  troquei de antivirus.﻿